# Use rules of inferential logic for the following problem..

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

Here I have such a question related to laws of inference. The question asks to prove using the laws of inference ([these rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference)) that the following facts give a certain conclusion. So the question is:

> All the students that studied passed the exam. Ann passed the exam.So, I can say that Ann studied.

What I thought is: Generally we are talking about students. The statements are:

*P(x): "**x** studied"* and *Q(x): "**x** passed the exam"*

So the statment:

1. **All the students that studied passed the exam** is $\forall x(P(x) \to Q(x))$
2. **Ann passed the exam** is $Q(Ana)$

So I must prove that the conclusion is $P(Ana)$. The problem is I do not know what law of inference to use. The conclusion is obvious, but I do not understand how to show this thing using discrete math tools. Can you please help me ? Thanks.

Comment: "The problem is I do not know what law of inference to use". Right back at you. These laws aren't standard. Some people adopt one set of rules, others adopt other rules. What are yours?

Comment: @GitGud You know, I mean rules such as Modus Tolens, Modus Ponens,Disjunctive Syllogism ...

Comment: Seriously not being nitpicky, I do not know. For one, the rules you mentioned are propositional calculus rules, this is predicate calculus. Also, as I said, these rules aren't standard. You need to specify yours. Are you following a text book? Which?

Comment: If all Ferraris are red, are all red cars Ferraris?

Comment: @GitGud I do not know how to explain it otherwise. I'm using the rules of inferential logic, that I know are standard.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Ok, no, but how do I prove this mathematically ?

Comment: By pointing out a red Lamborghini.

Comment: Here are a list of "standard" [Rules of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference) : you have to start with *Universal Instantiation* (or *Universal Elimination*) to derive from 1. : $P(Ann) \rightarrow Q(Ann)$ and then ...

Comment: @JohnG. You know wrong, they aren't standard. I hadn't even read the problem, but as it has been pointed out, you can't prove it because it's false. You can't construct formal proofs of false statements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So the answer might be that we cannot draw a conclusion ? Because you see, after doing Universal Instantiation for the first statement I get $P(Ann)\to Q(Ann)$ and $Q(Ann)$, so I cannot deduce anything from this. So Ann , may have studied  and not. What do you thing, is it right ? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly; you cannot derive $P(Ann)$ from the two premises, because that argument is *invalid*; see [Affirming the consequent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much, dont you know , by the way why do I have a minus for my question ?

Comment: In order to prove that the "purported argument" concluding $P(Ann)$ is *invalid*, you have to show that the *conditional* $P(Ann) \rightarrow Q(Ann)$ is *true* also in case that $P(Ann)$ is *false* ($FALSE \rightarrow X$ is $FALSE$).

Comment: Because there are many different *proof systems* (i.e. different sets of rules); thus asking : "the question asks to prove using the laws of inference" implies that you gives us the list (or a reference to) of the rules you are allowed to use...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much.